# Multiple fields in a cell in MS Report Viewer

Tags: c#, .net, reporting, reportviewer

In a C# based Win forms application I am working on a report using Microsoft Report Viewer. There is a requirement that I have to display multiple fields in one cell of the table, all in a new line.

- I have tried to use new line characters in expression but didnt work. There is no multi-line property of textbox.
- I have tried to use a list with multiple textboxes in the cell. But
  it gives error that:

> The tablix has a detail member with inner members. Detail members can
>   only contain static inner members

Some people say something like adding groups but I could not figure how to do this.

Could you please let me know how can show multiple fields in row like:

```
Product Name
Product Color
Poduct Size
```

Thanks to @Hemant's suggestion I managed to solve it like this:

In Report -> Report Properties -> Code, I entered this code:

```
Function GetBreakupstring(value) as String

    return value.Replace("--M--", Environment.NewLine) 

End Function
```

In Textbox's expression I entered:

```
=Code.GetBreakupstring(Fields!Name.Value & "--M--" & Fields!IDProducts.Value & "--M--" & Fields!Color.Value)
```

Then I tried to simple use Environment.NewLine in expression which I also worked. This is what expression is looking right now:

```
=Fields!Name.Value & Environment.NewLine & Fields!IDProducts.Value & Environment.NewLine & Fields!Color.Value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write a function in VB Code that breaks your input into multiple line and call that function in text box
as
Textbox expression=  Code.GetBreakupstring(field.parameter)

and write this 
 public sub GetBreakupstring(value){

return break value;
  }